# How to make a div resizable like in (background-size:100%)?

Tags: css, resize, background-size

I want a div height/width to be dynamically resized together when window width is resizing just like in (background-size:100%), and I prefer using only CSS "if possible".

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What is wrong with a percent value, exactly like in your example?

Comment: Sorry, my fault! I figured out that it's easy to do it with Yamona's way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set width:100%; and height:auto;
Also try to do the same for images inside that div

```
img{
     width:100%
     height:auto;
}
```

That will make the img responsive and will not overflow the parent div

Also you can use this

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

The image will scale down if it has to, but never scale up to be larger than its original size

Answer (score 0):

If you select `width:100%` and `height:auto` it will make the div dimensions responsive to resizing the window.